# Jquery multidimensionnal array: can't convert undefined object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, undefined

I'm trying to fill my array with an auto-increment (listeFormatte.lenght) and it break at the line `listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length][0] = cartArray[i][0];` and give can't convert undefined object error.

```
cartArray[i][0] = "ensemble"

listeFormatte = "" (new array)

listeFormatte.length = 0
```

Thanks in advance.

```
var listeFormatte = new Array;

for(var i=0;i<cartArray.length;i++)
{
    if(cartArray[i][0] == "ensemble")
    {
        listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length] = [];
        listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length][0] = cartArray[i][0];
    }
}
```

Edit: What is imagemagick-convert it has nothing to do with what I'm doing, why would you edit my things with stuff like that?

Answer: So when listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length] = []; create the multidimensional array it raise the listeFormatte.lenght which lead to a undefined on the "second use" because it is now: listeFormatte[1] instead of [0]. So I added a variable which get the listeFormatte.length.

Comment: It gives the same error without the  listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length] = [];

Comment: I also tried using push on listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length] and got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider 
`listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length] = new Array;`

I never seen the `listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length] = [];` construct before, and without something like that your `listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length]` is NOT defined as array, so you can not use [0] index.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, it did exactly the same. Pretty sure = [] is just another way of saying it from jquery

Comment: I just realised what the problem is:  
After this line `listeFormatte[listeFormatte.length] = [];` executes what do you think is the value of `listeFormatte.length`?

Comment: Oh this is it. Thanks for the help! That was stupid from me not seeing that.

Comment: I did not notice it until later either, so don't beat yourself up.